# How to find out what is causing the commandline autocompletion menu (wildmode/menu) to close?

Tags: wildmenu

If I use the `<tab>` completion while typing in command mode, the full results listing will display above the commandline for just a moment, but then almost immediately disappear. If I hit tab again, the results will display, but only with the single line listing within the statusline, not in the "full" menu that showed before.

I've tried using `:profile` but after typing `:colo <tab>` to bring up the menu and then completing the profile commands, the resulting file is blank.

```
:profile start ~/profile.log | :profile func * | :profile file *
<do stuff>
:profile pause
:noautocmd qall!
```

Is there anything else I can use to see what may be happening in the background?

I also tried `:verbose au`, but that output doesn't seem related. (Or maybe it does show what I'm after and I'm not reading it properly?)

**options.lua**

```
wildmenu = true,
wildmode = "list:longest,list:full",
```

This does not happen when launching with `nvim -u NONE` so I suspect it's likely something on my end, either related to a plugin or to something in my config/keymaps/etc.

Comment: What happens if you run `vim --noplugins`? If that "fixes" it, then you can start bisecting based on your plugins. If not, start bisecting based on your settings. If the same behavior remains, then it is more likely caused by the interaction between user settings and plugins.

Comment: `--noplugin` it still happened. Bisected through my `options.lua` file and narrowed it down to the `wildmode = "list:longest,list:full"`. When commented out, the default "tall and narrow" menu displays and does NOT disappear.

Comment: Did you remove your other settings? I'm running `nvim -u NONE -c "set wildmenu | set wildmode=list:longest,list:full"` and seems to be working fine: https://i.imgur.com/pJjhTkp.gif

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the output of `:verbose cmap <Tab>` using your configuration settings?

Comment: Oh very cool! I never knew you could pass in custom options after `-u NONE`!

Starting with the command you listed, it *DOES* work as expected.

Output of `:verbose cmap <Tab>` is `No mapping found`

https://imgur.com/u84prVT

Interesting...

Comment: It is certainly unusual. When you were bisecting your configuration file, did you prevent other files from loading. I ask this because you seem to have other files other than options.lua. You can also grep recursively and see if you have `cmap`,  `cnoremap`, or autocommands that could be the real culprit.  If that doesn't work, post a minimal, reproducible example (no plugins and only relevant settings enabled). I wasn't able to replicate this behavior in the latest neovim (v0.8.0-dev-784), by the way.

Comment: Okay so quick question. When I'm going through and disabling and enabling various `require x` references in my `init.lua` file, can I get away with saving then `:so %`-ing things, or do I need to fully close out and re-open each time? Thank you again for your help and tips @r_31415 , I'll work on it this weekend and follow-up :)

Comment: Got it! Turns out it's something related to lualine! Thank you so much for teaching me a bit more vim-fu for how to navigate these sorts of hiccups @r_31415 !

Comment: @Spectator6 you need to fully close and re-open. `:source` executes commands in a file; you need (Neo)Vim to "forget" all of the current state. It sounds like you found the issue, so I'm going to close this

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you figured it out. Actually, I found the bug causing this issue here: https://github.com/nvim-lualine/lualine.nvim/issues/781. I suppose this was opened by other user, right?

Comment: Good find! And yes, that's someone else, I was going to open one myself if I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Great, thank you @D.BenKnoble !